# How to a call an api endpoint that uses Cognito implicit grant Authorization with aws java SDK

Tags: java, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

Currently trying to create some acceptance tests that are to call api endpoints which have been authenticated with Cognito implicit grant.

Is there a possible way of using the aws sdk and Cognito sdk to request for an access key to call my api endpoints?
Im finding very little help through the aws documentation and on the internet in general.

My acceptance test run on java with cucumber and gherkin.

Answer (score 0):

You can authenticate via Cognito API's `initiateAuth` to get the tokens directly.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html

The default way of authentication requires SRP.

If you wanted, you could avoid SRP overhead implementation by creating a separate app client for testing and checking off `Enable username-password (non-SRP) flow for app-based authentication (USER_PASSWORD_AUTH)` in the `App Clients` settings for that app client.

You probably want to have some deployment configuration so that this app client is only available in testing environments. Otherwise, you could create a secret for the app client.

Other than `USER_PASSWORD_AUTH` flow, there is `ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH` via `adminInitiateAuth` which requires AWS keys (must be enabled in "App Client" settings as well).

You can learn more about these flows here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html?icmpid=docs_cognito_console#amazon-cognito-user-pools-admin-authentication-flow

Comment: So i've done what you've said, however the access token generated doesnt see to work when passed in the header in the format of:

        "Authentication: Bearer {accessTokenValue}"

However when testing the token through the api gateway, it fails on access token but passes when providing the Id Token

Comment: API Gateway's Cognito Authorizer by default takes Id Token. You can switch it to take Access Token instead. See Step 7 of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html.

Note: You don't need to create a custom OAuth scope. You can provide the default one(s) that are provided, for example: "openid".